# Cannot call enlive snippet via its name stored in a variable

Tags: clojure, enlive

I'm trying to do something simple with Clojure Enlive lib: I want the top menu of my page to be different based on language selected by the user (English or Japanese). I can't find how to implement this basic feature.

I have a "template/header.html" template with 2 sections (one per language):

```
<div class="header en-US">...</div>
<div class="header ja-JP">...</div>
```

I created 2 corresponding snippets in my templating code:

```
(:require [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
...
(html/defsnippet header-ja-JP "templates/header.html" [:div.header.ja-JP] [])
(html/defsnippet header-en-US "templates/header.html" [:div.header.en-US] [])
```

Now when I load my main template (index.html) I want to populate my header menu code into my nav tag.

Below, the argument 'lang' value is either "en-US" or "ja-JP":

```
(defn process-template
  [lang]
  (let [header-selector  (str “header-“ lang)
        header-content   (@(resolve (symbol header-selector)))]
    (apply str
           (html/emit*
            (html/at
             (html/html-resource "templates/index.html")
             [:nav] (html/content (header-content)))))))
```

It throws a java.lang.NullPointerException

If I replace the last line by

```
[:nav] (html/content (header-ja-JP)))))))
```

or

```
[:nav] (html/content (header-en-US)))))))
```

it works fine (so the snippets work), but I've tried lots of different syntaxes and can't make the dynamic header work based on language.

The above code (let part) seems ok if I execute it manually in REPL, the header-content is JSON object containing the correct content so I don't understand why I get a NullPointerException.

Ideally I think I should have only one snippet taking the language as argument and returning the corresponding HTML section, but didn't manage to do that either.

I'm very new at Clojure so I'm probably missing something obvious here; if someone could point me to what's wrong in the code above or another way to make this work that will be awesome.

Thanks,
Olivier

Comment: Like @deadghost I guess the parens around the `@(resolve ...)` are not needed. I could even say that the `@` itself should be removed. However the call to `resolve` is half way to evil (evail as in eval). What about having a map of `{"ja-JP" header-ja-JP ...}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to do it differently as `cgrand` suggests, there are many, many ways to accomplish this. I have a hard time imagining how he'd do it with maps, but I'd do it this way:

```
(defn process-template [lang]
  (html/select (html/html-snippet
                 "<html>
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                      <nav>
                        <div class=\"en\"></div>
                        <div class=\"jp\"></div>
                      </nav>
                    </body>
                  </html>") 
        [(keyword (str "div." lang))]))

(apply str (html/emit* (process-template "en")))
=> "<div class=\"en\"></div>"
```

Of course read it from file instead of `HTML` in a string. The function plucks out the matching `HTML` node according to a selector.

Comment: Thanks very much. Indeed I initially tried to have only one snippet instead of one per language (not very pretty) but couldn't figure out how to make the selector dynamic. Wrapping this inside a function is a nice way to do it, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `(@(resolve (symbol header-selector)))` returns a value.
`(resolve (symbol header-selector))` returns a function.

`[:nav] (html/content (header-content)))))))` calls `header-content` as a function.

Replace `(@(resolve (symbol header-selector)))` with `(resolve (symbol header-selector))`.

I'm fuzzy on what `html/at` and `html/html-resource` do so if other problems crop up you might need to cram in `clojure.java.io/file` in there.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation, very clear. After spending quite some time struggling with this I started to better understand how Clojure works (rather the syntax) and what you just explained now makes perfect sense. Thanks again.